# How to initalize spring bean for separation between tests in junit?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I'm using `Junit5` and `Spring` for test.
I want to initalize `spring bean` for each test because **I don't want different tests to change the other results of tests.**
I'm knowing that a new instance of the test class is created before running each test method by default. under result of test codes is true,because **the instance variable number is initalized for each test** by junit5.

```
public class TestInstanceVaribale{
    
    int number = 0;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        number += 3;
        Assertions.assertEquals(3, number);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test2() {
        number += 5;
        Assertions.assertEquals(5, number);
    }
}
```

but, this code is failed because spring bean is not initalized.

```
@Component
public class Car {

    public String name = "myCar";
}
```

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;

@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class TestSpringVariable {

    @Autowired
    Car car;
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void test1() {
        car.name = "testCar";
        Assertions.assertEquals("testCar", car.name);
    }
    
    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void test2() {
        // this is fail. expected: <myCar> but was: <testCar>
        // but I want expected: <myCar> but was: <myCar>
        Assertions.assertEquals("myCar", car.name); 
    }
}
```

How to initalize `spring bean` for separation between tests in junit?

```
@SpringBootTest
@initalizeSpringBeanPerMethod <-- I want like this
public class TestSpringVariable2 {

    @Autowired
    Car car;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void initalize() { <-- I want like this
        SpirngBean.initalize()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DirtiesContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)

Probably adding this to your class should work. It's telling Spring to reset it's state after/before (depending on how you set it) each test

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```